# Windows Task Scheduler not allowing python subprocess.popen

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I noticed a rather interesting problem the other day.

I have a windows scheduled task on Windows server 2008 RT. This task runs a batch file which runs a python script I've built. Within this python script there is a subprocess.Popen call to run several other batch files. However for the past couple days I've noticed that the task has successfully run however the secondary batch files did not. I know the python script ran successfully due to the logs it created and all the files it makes that the secondary batch files use are all there. However the completed files are not.

If I just run the batch file by itself everything works perfectly. Does Microsoft's task scheduler not allow a program to open additional batch files and is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Are you wrapping the Popen() in an exception + piping its stdout/err and logging it all? What does it say? Could be a permissions problem or even a current directory problem.

Comment: actually I didnt, adding that now and Ill print the results

Comment: I've hit this same problem and can't find a satisfying technical explanation for it, but I _was_ able to work around it by changing the scheduled task to calling psexec.exe (from sysinternals) -d -h -I c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c python.exe (etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem when task scheduler tries to call a .bat which runs a python script.

I found the trick is to put the path of the bat file in Start in (optional)

[image]

Thanks to answer from Jordan8307
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/531774-task-scheduler-fails-executing-bat-file-but-i-can-run-it-manually

Answer (score 0):

Same situation: taks -> batch script -> Python process -> subprocess(es), but on Windows Server 2012

I worked around the problem by providing the absolute path to the script/exe in `subprocess.Popen`.

I verified the environment variables available inside the Python process and the script/exe is in a directory on the `PATH`. Still, Windows gives a `FileNotFoundError` unless I provide the absolute path.

Strangely, calling the same script/exe from the batch script is possible without providing its absolute path.